# Counting integral coordinate points inside the region bounded by two parabolas

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, integer-lattices

If we consider two parabolas $y^2=4ax$ and other one $x^2=4ay$. Both parabolas meet at origin and some other point for reference consider $(x_1,y_1)$ .Now we have to find number of integral points between the enclosed part which is between $(0,0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$. How to pursue finding it? From my point of view I would draw constant lines in the region such as $y=1$, $y=2$, $y=3$ or $x=1$, $x=2$, $x=3$ and try to find symmetry between the points But this won't help instead of making the question lengthy. So what can be the other useful approach to this?

Thanks

Comment: 1) I have made your title more precise in order it attracts more people. Do you agree ? 2) Have you attempted a computer simulation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks a lot  for the help :) and I haven't attempted a computer simulation.

Comment: A computer simulation shows that the count for a given $a$ is $\approx 5.33  a^2$ but I haven't any idea for a rigorous approach. What are the lectures in which you have this homework ? Number theory ?

Comment: This looks like an open problem (a problem which hasn't been solved yet) ; see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.06047.pdf). One thing is certain : the number of integer coordinate points is of the same order of magnitude as the enclosed area. Do you see why ? (make a reasonning on squares with area one centered in these lattice points).

Comment: Last comment : begin by computing explicitly the coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ of the second intersection point.

Comment: @JeanMarie It is an old Olympiad problem but Instead of 2 parabolas there was 1 parabola and 1 circle.

Comment: I am posting this comment out of curiosity. My approach, with which I obtained the following formula is slightly different, i.e., instead of drawing lines parallel to axes, I drew lines parallel to the line $y=x$. With this approach, I needed to consider grid points only in half of the mentioned area. My question is this. Did you also get a similar formula?
$$\large{N=\lfloor 4a\rfloor +1+2\left( \lfloor a\rfloor +\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor a\rfloor} \left(\lfloor 2a+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rfloor-\lceil 2a-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rceil \right)\right)}$$

Comment: @YNK I is a pity that the asker of this question doesn't want to show his/her work and have exchanges with us beyond elementary comments... Maybe ask a question of your own with your formula. I would be happy to discuss about it (and upvote it !). Let me know...

Comment: @YNK Actually I didn't got any formula my answer was like I had to use Permutation and combination and some of the symmetry.

Comment: @JeanMarie I gave some thoughts about your suggestion to post my own question. But, I decided against it and posted an answer istead. I hope you are not displeased with me for doing that.

Comment: It's very fine like this. Your answer brings a good methology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: TwoParabolae]

As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, two parabolae $x^2=4ay$ and $y^2=4ax$ intersect at $O_1\space (0,0)$ and $O_2\space (4a,4a)$. The region bounded by this pair of parabolae is symmetrical about the line $O_1O_2$, the equation of which is $y=x$. Therefore, in order to find a formula that gives the number of lattice points inside the mentioned region, we need to find the number of points that lie within only one half of it. Please note that all lattice points under consideration lie on lines, which are parallel to $O_1O_2$ and pass through the integral points on the $y-$axis

It can be also shown that the line $y=x+a$, which is parallel to $O_1O_2$, is tangent to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ at $D_1\space (a,2a)$. Therefore, the line parallel to $O_1O_2$, which passes thorough $C\space (0,\lfloor a\rfloor)$ is the furthest line from $O_1O_2$, which also goes through a set of lattice points. Our aim is to find the lattice points on all lines such as $y=x+m$, where $m$ is an integer and $0\le m\le\lfloor a\rfloor$.

The line $y=x+m$ intersects the parabola $y^2=4ax$ at $B_1$ and $B_2$. Their coordinates are as follows;
$$B_1 = (2a-m-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m},\space\space 2a-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}), \quad\text{where}\quad a\ge m $$
$$B_2 = (2a-m+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m},\space\space 2a+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}), \quad\text{where}\quad a\ge m.$$

If $\bar{B}_1$ and $\bar{B}_2$ are the two nearest lattice points to $B_1$ and $B_2$ respectively, we can express their coordinates as shown below. As the previous pair of expressions, they are also valid if and only if $a\ge m$.
$$\bar{B}_1 = (\lceil 2a-m-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rceil,\space\space \lceil 2a-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rceil)$$
$$\bar{B}_2 = (\lfloor 2a-m+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rfloor,\space\space  \lfloor 2a+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rfloor)$$

Number of lattice points $n_m$ lying on $B_1B_2$ is one more than the difference between either $x-$ or $y-$coordinates of the lattice points $\bar{B}_1$ and $\bar{B}_2$. Therefore, we shall write,
$$n_m = \lfloor 2a+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rfloor  - \lceil 2a-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rceil +1.\tag{1}$$

In a similar vein, we can express the number of lattice points $n_0$ located on the line of symmetry $O_1O_2$ as,
$$n_0 = \lfloor 4a\rfloor - \lceil 0\rceil +1 = \lfloor 4a\rfloor +1.\tag{2}$$

Now, we are in a position to write down the formula for the total number of lattice point $N$ inside and on the border of the region in question.
$$N=n_0+2\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor a\rfloor} n_m \tag{3}$$

When we substitute (1) and (2) in (3), we get,
$${\small{\text{For}\space a\ge 1}}\quad N=\lfloor 4a\rfloor +1+2\left( \lfloor a\rfloor +\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor a\rfloor} \left(\lfloor 2a+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rfloor-\lceil 2a-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-m}\rceil \right)\right),$$
$\space{\small{\text{For}\space a\le 1}}\quad N=\lfloor 4a\rfloor +1.$

As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, the graph of Number-of-Lattice-Point vs $a$ and its second order polynomial trend curve are hugging each other so closely, we see only one of them. This is no wonder, because the measure of goodness-of-fit $R^2$ is equal to 1. It also improves the estimate given by @JeanMarie in one of his comments from $N\approx 5.33a^2$ to $N\approx 5.3447a^2$.

[image: TwoParabolae2]

Why is the number of lattice points one more than the difference between the $x−$ or $y−$coordintes of the last and the first lattice ponts?

Let us imagine a straight fence erected to divide two plots of land. This fence has $\space\large{n}\space$ number of $\large{\text{1-meter}}$-spaced upright poles and the poles are numbered from $\large{1}$ to $\large{n}$. If we assume that the number given to each pole is either its $x-$ or $y-$coordinate, then each number represents a grid point along the chosen axis. Since there are $\large{n}$ number of poles,  there are $\large{n}$ number of grid points. Now, if you subtract the number or the coordinate given to the last pole (i.e., $\large{n}$ ) from the number or the coordinate given to the first pole (i.e., $\large{1}$ ), you get $\large{n-1}$ as their difference. But, there are $\large{n}$ number of poles ( or grids points), which is one more than the difference.

Comment: If you read russian : https://www.mathnet.ru/links/6c1a754f8e7beba3f5e21e3047c07d7f/mzm7681.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie The only foreign languages I know are English and Deutsch. So I searched and found the English translation of the mentioned article. Thanks!

Comment: Being not more versed into Russian than you, I would be interested by this translation. Could you give its references ?

Comment: An article in continuation of the article of Popov [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13715.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie Here is the [link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01153567) for the English translation. However, you have to log in via an institution.

Comment: @YNK Thank you for the help man +1 :) I must use computational graph onwards

Comment: @YNK Can you explain how number of lattice point is more than the difference of either x or y coordinate of lattice B1 and B2

Comment: @πααρτθΣαρθι  No, it is not ${\large{B}}_1$ and ${\large{B}}_2$. I think you have not seen the bar over ${\large{\bar{B}}}_1$ and ${\large{\bar{B}}}_2$.

Comment: @YNK Yes, sorry for the mistake but still how number of lattice point is more than the difference

Comment: @πααρτθΣαρθι I added a paragraph to the end of my answer to explain why the number of lattice points is one more than the difference between the $x−$ or $y−$coordintes of the last and the first lattice points.